# save and laod image using universal image loader

Tags: android, caching, picasso

**Updated**

So as suggested earlier, i used Universal image loader. But i am getting some error.
**This is the first time i am playing around with this kind of stuff.

Below are my codes :

Here is the code to save bitmap to internal storage using async:

```
Uri uri = Crop.getOutput(result);

        try {
            bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            new saveDpToDisk().execute(bmp);
        }
class saveDpToDisk extends AsyncTask{

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput("ProPic", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, fos);
        return bmp;
    }
}
```

and here is code to load image from storage using UIL:

```
@Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {

        FileInputStream fis;
        try {
            fis = openFileInput("ProPic");
            String uri = String.valueOf(fis);
            DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheOnDisk(true).build();
            ImageLoader loader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
            loader.displayImage(uri, pro_pic, options);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return pro_pic;
    }
}
```

And this is the error I am getting (app doesnt force close, error just appears in logcat

```
UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [java.io.FileInputStream@42987180]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [java.io.FileInputStream@42987180]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(BaseImageDownloader.java:235)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:97)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.downloadImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:290)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryCacheImageOnDisk(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:273)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:229)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:135)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

________x_____________________x___________________________x_______________________

**Original Question**

My app has to load only one image (which user can select from gallery to set as his dp for that app).

So, **What I did** is I saved the selected pic to storage using FileOutputStream and then load the pic using FileInputStream in activity's onResume method.

But, what happens is that when the selected pic is too large, the app starts up too slowly (takes time to inflate view) and logcat shows memory heap of 30-60 MB.

So, i thought of storing the image in cache and load but dont exactly find a way to do so.

Shall i use **picasso**? If yes, how to use it for saving and laoding from cache.

Or are there any other ways to achieve what i need?

Comment: picasso and other library are use load image from url generally not use for local image cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read [this](https://plus.google.com/103583939320326217147/posts/bfAFC5YZ3mq) post on G+ by Koush you will get clear solutions for your confusions, I have put the summery of that, in that  Android-Universal-Image-Loader is the winner for your requirement!

- **[Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)** has the nicest image API if you are using network!
- **[UrlImageViewHelper](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper) + [AndroidAsync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync)** is the fastest. Playing with these 
  other two great libraries have really highlighted that the image API 
  is quite dated, however.
- **[Volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley)** is slick; I really enjoy their pluggable backend transports,
  and may end up dropping AndroidAsync in there. The request priority
  and cancellation management is great(if you are using network)
- **[Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)** is the most popular one out there
  currently. Highly customizable.

> This project aims to provide a reusable instrument for asynchronous
>   image loading, caching and displaying. It is originally based on Fedor
>   Vlasov's project and has been vastly refactored and improved since
>   then.

Considering all this Android-Universal-Image-Loader suites your requirement (*Loading the images are on disk locally*)!

Comment: thank you for this. it was very useful. so i decided to go with Universal Image Loader.

Comment: But i still dont exactly got how to use that. i mean suppose i updated the pic in the image view (using cacheInMemory(true)). then what m i supposed to do? am i supposed to save it to storage and again load it from there in onResume or UIL will do it by itself?

Comment: It will load last cache image before updating new URI image, and as soon as new thumbnail is loaded in memory it will refresh your ImageView.

Comment: Well, that simple line solved a big mystery for me :p. Thnxx a lot

Comment: i got into another problem. i updated the question. m sorry to bother u but this is the firest time i m playing around with this kind of stuff

Comment: Are you trying to load image from asset folder?

Comment: no .from internal storage where i saved it. look at saveToDisk asynctask class in the code above.

Comment: if you are using from Asset folder then modify your URI as : `String imageUri = "assets://your folder/your image.png";` // from Asset folder

if you are using image from `sd card` then try this: `String imageUri = "file:///mnt/sdcard/image.png";` // from SD card`